# How to write Mockito for Rest template 2 based response from RestTemplate 1

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

```
 @Test
    public void getEventsByOrg() throws Exception {

        String mockResposne = getXMLFromFile("classpath:OrgResponse.xml");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<>(mockResposne, HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(any(String.class), any(), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class)))
                .thenReturn(response);

        ResponseEntity<List<OCVEvents>> ocvEvents = eventService.getEventsByGlobalKey(eventIdOrg, traceId);
        verify(restTemplate).exchange(any(String.class), any(), captor.capture(), any(Class.class));

        Events event = ocvEvents.getBody().get(0);
        Events eventsPerson = new ObjectMapper().readValue(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:EventOrg.json"), Events.class);
        assertThat(event.getHeader()).isEqualTo(eventsPerson.getHeader());
```

Now i have another Rest Call inside eventsService 
How to write unit test for that

I need to hit a Rest API(1) & get the response, based on response i need to hit another Rest API (2)
i need to write the mockit0 for this class

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rest api calls being made in your service class , you will have to mock all the api calls to return a mock data for your test to run. Just like you mocked the response for the first api call, add a mock response for the second api call before calling your service in you test. Instead of using `any()` as the argument matcher specify the particular url that you are going to be calling from the code to differentiate between the two api call mocks.

If you are on Springboot and using `spring-boot-test` for Integration testing , then you could use `TestRestTemplate` like:

```
TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.
  getForEntity(FOO_RESOURCE_URL + "/1", String.class);

assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
```

or If you are just having a Unit test case using Mockito for instance then :

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private EventService eventService = new EventService();

@Test
public void givenMockingIsDoneByMockito_whenGetIsCalled_shouldReturnMockedObject() {
    SomeObject instance = new SomeObject(“E001”, "Eric Simmons");
    Mockito
      .when(restTemplate.getForEntity(
        “http://localhost:8080/test/E001”, SomeObject.class))
      .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(instance, HttpStatus.OK));

    SomeObject returnedObject = eventService.getEventsByGlobalKey(id);
    Assert.assertEquals(instance, returnedObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this now

Comment: @Karthik Please share your code for more assistance.